# How to make TCK_QUICKACK work in Python

Tags: python, linux, sockets, tcp

I want to implement tcp check with Python.

I found a magic way in this [article](https://yanagieiichi.github.io/tcp-check/docs/intro/#The%20tcp-check).

It introduce a efficient way to do a tcp-health-check.

```
Client: SYN
Server: SYN-ACK
Client: RST
```

I also found a Go implementer https://github.com/tevino/tcp-shaker.

But i hope to implement `SYN`,`SYN-ACK`,`RST` in python.

My code is there:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_QUICKACK, 0)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 0)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_LINGER, struct.pack('ii', 1, 0))
s.connect((ip, port))
s.close()
```

But it didn't work as I expected. The client send a `ACK` to the server when the `SYN-ACK` received from server.

How could I disable `TCP_QUICKACK` in Python?